# Can someone explain what the next() method in the Spotipy module does?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

birdy_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP'
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())

results = spotify.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
while results['next']:
     results = spotify.next(results)
     albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

After the while loop, does the loop move through the dictionary till it reaches `results[next]` in the first `results = spotify.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')` or `results = spotify.next(results)` and what does `spotify.next()` actually do? Read the documentation and it says

`returns the next result given a paged result` but I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.next

It is used in order to paginate over the results.

Example:
If your search retuned 10,000 results, those 10,000 records are not returned at once to the caller - they returned by pages. Each "page" is < 10,000. This is what next is doing - moving over the pages.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i now understand what `next()` does. But how does the while loop work?

Comment: loop over all "pages"

Comment: could I replace `while results[next]` with `while True`? or does the former loop through just the values of `results[next]` excluding other keys? @balderman

Comment: No. It's not looping through the values of results['next'], it's looping as long as results contains a non-false value for the next attribute.